# Pandas Timedelta gives error on Azure and not giving on Colab

Tags: pandas, azure, google-colaboratory, timedelta

I'm trying to convert the date with panda timedelta, and its work in colab, but gives error on Azure Notebooks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does it mean `PT1M0.48S`?

Comment: It's mean shown at the second ss over colab @Corralien